# XML to XSLT - Getting each character and converting into tags

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have the below XML as input.

```
<elements>
    <element>
        <column23>HNC141</column23>
    </element>
    <element>
        <column23>HNC14P3</column23>
    </element>
</elements>
```

and my desired output is below. first three character will be parent department after that every 1 character is need to be set as code. and in parent ref i need to concat the department with "."  ... for first three character there is no parent ref

```
<Department>
                <Code>HNC</Code>
                <FreeString10>HNC</FreeString10>
                <ParentRef/>
            </Department>
            <Department>

                <Code>1</Code>
                <FreeString10>HNC1</FreeString10>
                <ParentRef>HNC</ParentRef>
            </Department>
            <Department>

                <Code>4</Code>
                <FreeString10>HNC14</FreeString10>
                <ParentRef>HNC.1</ParentRef>
            </Department>
            <Department>

                <Code>1</Code>
                <FreeString10>HNC141</FreeString10>
                <ParentRef>HNC.1.4</ParentRef>
            </Department>

<Department>

            <Code>HNC</Code>
            <FreeString10>HNC</FreeString10>
            <ParentRef/>
        </Department>
        <Department>

            <Code>1</Code>
            <FreeString10>HNC1</FreeString10>
            <ParentRef>HNC</ParentRef>
        </Department>
        <Department>

            <Code>4</Code>
            <FreeString10>HNC14</FreeString10>
            <ParentRef>HNC.1</ParentRef>
        </Department>
        <Department>

            <Code>1</Code>
            <FreeString10>HNC141</FreeString10>
            <ParentRef>HNC.1.4</ParentRef>
        </Department>
        <Department>

            <Code>P</Code>
            <FreeString10>HNC14P</FreeString10>
            <ParentRef>HNC.1.4</ParentRef>
        </Department>
        <Department>

            <Code>3</Code>
            <FreeString10>HNC14P3</FreeString10>
            <ParentRef>HNC.1.4.P</ParentRef>
        </Department>
```

I am using this xslt for transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="fn"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <businessobjects>
        <xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
            <Department>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="column23"/>

                    <xsl:call-template name="for-each-character">                    
                        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="column23"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </Name>
            </Department>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </businessobjects>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="for-each-character">                
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($data) &gt; 0">
            <someTags>                            
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($data,1,3)"/>
            </someTags>
            <ParentRef><xsl:value-of select="substring($data,1,3)"/></ParentRef>
            <xsl:call-template name="for-each-character">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

help to get the desire output.

Comment: The output that you show us has some issues: it has no root element (not allowed in XML).  And the indentation is wrong and misleading: there is no separation between the original `element` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I would do it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/elements">
    <businessobjects>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element"/>
    </businessobjects>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="substring(column23, 1, 3)" />
    <xsl:variable name="chars" select="substring(column23, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="char-seq" select="for $i in 1 to string-length($chars) return substring($chars, $i, 1)"/> 
    <Department>
        <Code>
            <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
        </Code>
        <FreeString10>
            <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
        </FreeString10>
        <ParentRef/>
    </Department>
    <xsl:for-each select="$char-seq">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />   
        <Department>
            <Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Code>
            <FreeString10>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($code, substring($chars, 1, $i))"/>
            </FreeString10>
            <ParentRef>
                <xsl:value-of select="($code, $char-seq[position() lt $i])" separator="."/>
            </ParentRef>
        </Department>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<businessobjects>
   <Department>
      <Code>HNC</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef/>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC1</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef>HNC</ParentRef>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>4</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC14</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef>HNC.1</ParentRef>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC141</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef>HNC.1.4</ParentRef>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>HNC</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef/>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC1</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef>HNC</ParentRef>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>4</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC14</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef>HNC.1</ParentRef>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>P</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC14P</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef>HNC.1.4</ParentRef>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>3</Code>
      <FreeString10>HNC14P3</FreeString10>
      <ParentRef>HNC.1.4.P</ParentRef>
   </Department>
</businessobjects>
```